# How can I have a LINQ where clause that does nothing?

Tags: c#, linq, where-clause

I have this code that I am using to select a `Where` clause for application.

For the case of `CVM.IncludeHidden` I don't need to limit the rows and want to get everything.  But I am not sure how to do this. If that's the case what should I put for the `where` clause?

```
var select = " SELECT" +
                         " P.PhraseId, P.PhraseNum, P.English, P.Romaji, P.Kana, P.Kanji, P.Modified, P.WordType, P.Favorite," +
                         " P.Hidden, P.Viewed, P.Points, P.Score," +
                         " FROM Phrase" +
                         " WHERE P.Selected = 1 ";

List<Phrase> ps = db2.Query<Phrase>(select).ToList();
List<Phrase> psNoa = ps.Where(x => x.Points < noa).ToList();

Func<Phrase, bool> whereClause;

switch (Settings.cvm)
{
    case CVM.IncludeHidden:
        // I don't want to do any limiting
        // here I just want all records
        whereClause = ??
        break;
    case CVM.ExcludeHidden:
        whereClause = x => x.Hidden == false;
        break;
    case CVM.Hidden:
        whereClause = x => x.Hidden == true;
        break;
    case CVM.Favorites:
        whereClause = x => x.Favorite == true;
        break;
    default:
        return null;
}

return new SelectedPhrases()
{
    ps = ps.Where(whereClause).ToList(),
    psNoa = psNoa.Where(whereClause).ToList()
};

public class SelectedPhrases
{
    public List<Phrase> ps { get; set; }
    public List<Phrase> psNoa { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How about `whereClause = x => true`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Where` extension method just checks if the outcome of the function is `true`. If so, it passes. So simply returning `true` is enough:

```
whereClause = x => true;
```

It seems you are creating a new list for no reason. It hits your performance if you execute that a lot. You could also set `whereClause` to `null`, and just check it before you return the object:

```
if (whereClause != null)
{
    return new SelectedPhrases()
        {
            ps = ps.Where(whereClause).ToList(),
            psNoa = psNoa.Where(whereClause).ToList()
        };
}
else
{
    return new SelectedPhrases()
        {
            ps = ps,
            psNoa = psNoa
        };
}
```